# Check for double white-space in class declaration

Tags: java, checkstyle

How can checkstyle warn about class declarations like this:

```
public static class  VERSION {
    public static int SDK_INT = 20;
}
```

There is a double-white space before VERSION, but checkstyle should warn about this, as it should be only one.

Comment: Are you creating your own checkstyle?

Comment: No, I'm looking for the checkstyle configuration option which warns about the double white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ready-made check for this purpose afaik, but you can make use of [RegexpSinglelineJava](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_regexp.html#RegexpSinglelineJava#RegexpSinglelineJava) in order to achieve your goal:

```xml
<module name="RegexpSinglelineJava">
    <property name="format" value="\S\s\s+(?=\S).*$"/>
    <property name="message" value="Superfluous whitespace"/>
    <property name="ignoreComments" value="true"/>
</module>
```

Put this under `TreeWalker`. [The above regex](https://regex101.com/r/hK0dI2/1) is chosen so that leading and trailing spaces do not count.

You will have some false positives in Strings ... avoiding those would require much more work on the regex. But this is all you can do short of writing your own check I believe.

Comment: I recommend adding `<suppress id="superfluous-whitespace" files=".*Test.java" />` to avoid tests which often may contain block-aligned code (with extra whitespaces). Note, you'll need to add `<property name="id" value="superfluous-whitespace"/>` to the module to add the id.